# Is It possible to use the Xamarin.IOS or Xamarin.Android code for Xamarin Windows Phone development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xamarin

I have developed ios and Android applications using xamarin c#, is it possible to make Windows Phone app using Xamarin.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you've developed apps for iOS and Droid on the Xamarin framework without realising which of the mobile platforms it provides support for. A simple Google search will inform you that it does indeed support windows phone apps https://xamarin.com/platform

Answer (score 2):

If you have a business licence, you get the whole cross platform Xamarin experience in Visual Studio, and you'd know the answer to your own question, so I'm assuming you have the indie licence with Xamarin studio (like myself) instead.

You can't create Xamarin windows phone apps in Xamarin Studio, but you can in Visual Studio if you install the necessary Xamarin packages via nuget.

This is how I currently work (achieving the same thing):

1) On my mac I have Xamarin Studio where I have a solution creating Xamarin.Forms apps for IOS and Android

2) On my Visual Studio IDE in my Windows 8 VM I have a Windows Phone app with nuget packages installed for Xamarin.Forms

3) I have a shared Xamarin.Forms project where all my code and UI goes, and it is shared with all three projects (IOS,Android and Windows Phone).

This setup is far from ideal, but I can get all three mobile platforms working in Xamarin. Ideally I'd have a business licence, but it is vastly cost-prohibitive

Answer (score 0):

If you have a licence for Visual Studio with Xamarin, you get the whole cross platform Xamarin experience in Visual Studio itself. Its easy to create in the windows phone from those apps by using shared code concept.